# Multiple C2DM push notifications for the same app?

Tags: android, notifications, android-c2dm

In my app, users can "subscribe" to different types of resources (like a thread on a forum).
What i want to do : 
I want to send a push notification only to the users who subscribed to a specific resource.
Is it possible with c2dm ?

What I can/could do natively : send a push notification to ALL my users and programatively dispatch the notification only if the user subscribed to the resource ... but since I have PLENTY of resources, the quota would exceed rapidly.
So i want to restrict the push notification as much as I can.

If I understood the c2dm mechanism, the registrationID is the key here. Can I inject some custom logic when I call the com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER intent ?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't provide any logic in registration mechanism, but you can save subscribe information on your server, and send only necessary C2DM messages.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I had't thought of that. It should work perfectly !